Qt6 - QAbstractTableModel to create Bar chart in qml. How to define column names?
I have a ChartView  that has a BarSeries. I use VBarModelMapper to get the model. I have managed to get the values I want. But what I have not been able to do is to display "names" for the legend labels. I use a switch case that switches based on index.column(). This gives the legend labels value according to what number the column is. So for third column the label is 3. I want this to be a string I can decide.
main.qml
Item{
Layout.fillHeight: true
Layout.fillWidth: true
Layout.columnSpan: 2
    ChartView
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        theme: ChartView.ChartThemeDark
        antialiasing: true
        legend.visible: true
        title: "Loans"
    
        CategoryAxis {
            id: axisX
            labelsPosition: CategoryAxis.AxisLabelsPositionOnValue
            titleText: "Borrower"
        }
        
        ValueAxis {
            id: axisY
            min: 0
            max: 10000
            tickCount: 5
            titleText: "Total Loan"
        }
        
        BarSeries
        {
            id: barSeries
            axisX: axisX
            axisY: axisY

        }
        
        
        
        VBarModelMapper
        {
            id: modelMapper
            firstBarSetColumn: 2
            lastBarSetColumn: 3
            firstRow: 0
            model: ParticipantModel
            rowCount: ParticipantModel.rowCount()
            series: barSeries
        }
        
        Component.onCompleted: {
            // Populate CategoryAxis with categories from LoanModel
            for (var i = 0; i < ParticipantModel.rowCount(); ++i) {
                axisX.append(ParticipantModel.data(ParticipantModel.index(i,1), 
ParticipantModel.NameRole), i);
            }
        }

    
    }
}

ParticipantModel.cpp
ParticipantModel::ParticipantModel(QObject* parent, DatabaseConnector* databaseConnector)
{
    try
    {
        Init();
    }
    catch (RegulatorExceptionThrower& exception)
    {
        qCritical() << exception.exceptionMessage();
    }

}

ParticipantModel::~ParticipantModel()
{
}

int ParticipantModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return m_participants.size();
}

int ParticipantModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return 4;
}

QVariant ParticipantModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    qDebug() << index.isValid() << " " << index.row() << " " << m_participants.size();
    qDebug() << "Role" << role;
    qDebug() << "Row" << index.row();
    qDebug() << "Column" << index.column();
    if (!index.isValid() || index.row() >= m_participants.size())
        return {};

    Participant* participant = m_participants[index.row()];

    QHash<int, QString> columns = columnNames();

    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        switch (index.column())
        {
        case 0:
            return participant->GetParticipantId();
        case 1:
            return participant->GetName();
        case 2:
            return participant->GetLoans();
        case 3:
            return participant->GetLendings();
        default:
            return {};
        }
    }

    switch (role)
    {
    case ParticipantIdRole:
        return participant->GetParticipantId();
    case NameRole:
        return participant->GetName();
    case LoansRole:
        return participant->GetLoans();
    case LendingsRole:
        return participant->GetLendings();
    default:
        return {};
    }
}

void ParticipantModel::Init()
{
    beginResetModel();
    m_participants.clear();

    try
    {
    
        QList<quint64> participantIdList = GetParticipantIds(*m_databaseConnector);
        
        for (int i = 1; i < participantIdList.size(); i++)
        {
            Participant* participant = new Participant(i);

            m_participants.append(participant);
        }
    }

    catch (RegulatorExceptionThrower& exception)
    {
        qCritical() << exception.exceptionMessage();
    }

    emit maxLoanAmountChanged();

    endResetModel();
}

double ParticipantModel::maxLoanAmount() const
{
    return m_maxLoanAmount;
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> ParticipantModel::roleNames() const
{
    qDebug() << "roleNames() called";
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[ParticipantIdRole] = "ParticipantId";
    roles[NameRole] = "Name";
    roles[LoansRole] = "Loans";
    roles[LendingsRole] = "Lendings";
    roles[BirthRole] = "BirthDate";
    return roles;
}

I have tried to change the roles[Role] in roleNames() to have the column values insted
like roles[1] = "Name", but did not have any success with that.

Roles are not columns. See QAbstractItemModel::headerData() and check the model/view programming guide to understand the purpose of roles.

@musicamante Worked withQAbstractItemModel::headerData().
